# Cache Dynamic Pages - W3 Total Cache Plugin

Tags: performance, wordpress, caching, dynamic

I have a wordpress website and it runs pretty slow. I would like to speed it up by using w3 total cache but i have a few questions before i start to use it.

My website is a real estate listing site that displays the most recent homes for sale.  The real estate data is updated daily.

In theory, I would like to cache the page so that it loads quickly but still load the most recent (fresh) real estate data. Is there a way to cache the page but have it fetch the most recent real estate listings?  Real estate listing are display via a shortcode.

My fear is that if i use cache to speed up my site that it will display old listings.  Is there a way to set up w3 total cache (or any other cache plugin) so that my dynamic real estate pages load faster (instant) but still fetch the most recent real estate data.  Again, the real estate data is updated daily and I need to make sure my pages display the most current results while at the same time loading very quick.

I have made indexes on the real estate db and cleaned up my code but the search pages still runs very slow.  When i visit other real state sites they load very fast.  How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the plugin there was a section where i could exclude certain pages.  Seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to go to the browser cache settings tab of the plugin and set the expires time for HTML to something like 3600 seconds if you're worried about users not seeing updates for pages that are cached.